# WSO2 ESB iterate over a repeating structure

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I need to create a complex Repeating structure based on the incoming request which has a totally different structure.
Is there anyway to do this in the WSO2 ESB.
The iterate mediator only helps in sending multiple requests to an endpoint from a single repeating  structure.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood it right what you want to achive. With the iterate mediator you can e.g. iterate to an xml structure and for every iteration you can call a mediator, sequence, endpoint whatever. What we currently do is we receive a xml request with a lot of data rows and for every data row we insert this into a db (I know inserting every single row isn't nice)

If you need to create a new structure, you might use XSLT. An example of how to convert e.g. JSON to XML can be found here.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Sample+440%3A+Converting+JSON+to+XML+Using+XSLT

Another option might be to use the script mediator. Same example as above can be found here.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Sample+441%3A+Converting+JSON+to+XML+Using+JavaScript

Hope that helps, otherwise please provide more details what you want to achive.

Comment: Hey Martin,
No I do not want to convert from json to xml or vice versa.
I receive a request in format say :
<root><details><custName>John</custName><custId>1</custId></details>
<details><custName>Larry</custName><custId>2</custId></details>
</root>
Based on the abv format need to map to below structure and send to another web service:
<Customers><customerDetails><name>John</name><serialId>1</serialId></customerDetails>
<customerDetails><name>Larry</name><serialId>2</serialId></customerDetails>
</Customers>
<details><custName>Larry</custName><custId>2</custId></details>

Answer (score 0):

Then you can defintely use XSLT. The XML to JSON was just an example. You can also do XML to XML.

Regards
Martin